# Websocket bi-directional concept with Nao robot

Tags: javascript, android, ios, websocket, nao-robot

I’m developeing cool app for Nao but need that Nao control an external IOS, Android or Node.js (html5) application (samething like websocket that allows bi-directional communication). The clearest example would be the same as implemented in Pepper to communicate with the tablet.

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody kindly give me some feedback and examples on this type of development using Nao robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years ago, we were doing that the simpler way: you put some html with js and html5 page in the NAO's website. And your tablet access to the webpage and interact with it.

The good news, is you can use a computer instead of the tablet to develop; or even to deploy.

Comment: Researching NAOqi Framework, I think it can be done using QiMessaging, but I'm very junior programming with Nao. Do you have an code example? Or Is there any manual that I can review to have success? Thank you!

Comment: Even if junior in programming in NAO, you'll have to know how to program html and/or client/server and/or javascript. Have you look at the javascript naoqi binding, as explained there: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/js/index.html?highlight=javascript  ?

Comment: Thanks so much. Your advice was very helpful and gave me a new perspective on available alternatives.